# Send all linux logs to remote rsyslog and store in original file name

Tags: centos, httpd, rsyslog

I know there are alot of topics like this one but i have a particular need:
I need to send all the logs from linux servers to a central loggin server.

Problem 1:
On the central server i need to store the logs in the following format:

```
<root_dir>/<server_name>/<year>/<month>/<day>/{messages, mail, auth, httpd, etc}.log (the exact original file name of the log file)
```

The rsyslog server conf is

```
$template RemoteHost,"/var/log/remotes/%HOSTNAME%/%$YEAR%/%$MONTH%/%$DAY%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log" which creates the folder structure ok but for some logs it doesn't work (httpd logs)
```

Problem 2:
I need to send ALL logs.
On the remote servers (centOS) i configured the classic

```
*.* @@<central-server-hostname>:5544
```

but i see that httpd logs are not send (i thing it is because the filter is *.* and httpd logs are named like "httpd_acces" and does not match the filter.

Do you know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't use `syslog` by default, it just writes into some files defined in the Apache config by default.

You can either configure Apache to pipe the log to syslog, e.g. via `logger` or configure `rsyslog` to monitor the Apache files and send the content to the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Apache usually does not log through syslog. You would have to pipe the logs through `logger`, see [this guide](http://rafaelsteil.com/apache-remote-logging-with-rsyslog/). Not sure if that is a good idea performancewise.

`*.*` in syslog configuration not a file mask. It is a mask for `<facility>.<priority>` ... so something like `kern.error`. See the [docs](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html#selectors) for how it works.

Comment: Yes, i've seen the <facility>.<priority> thing. Now i have configured the source linux with /var/log/* @@<central-server-hostname>:5544 so that it sends all files from /var/log but i don't receive anything at the central server. Is the config not correct?

Comment: I've been searching the Internet and i've changed the client config to: $InputFileName /var/log/*
*.* @@<central-server-hostname>:5544 and now i receive log messages at the central server but still don't receive httpd logs. any ideas?

Comment: @ManeaDragosh did you do everything mentioned in the mentioned guide?